# Как импортировать данные из файла Excel в Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, xlrd

Пишу код в *VS Code*. 
Я написал `import xlrd` но выдается ошибка:

> Import "xlrd" could not be resolved.

Искал в интернете решения, но все они были для *Pycharm-а* .

Я вводил в терминале `pip install xlrd` , `pip3 install xlrd` , но это не помогло.Выводит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли решения этой проблемы для *VS Code*?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске без откладке выдает следующее:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd'

Comment: А чем запускаете? Это не похоже на ошибку, которую бы выдавал Python. Python при отсутствии модуля выдает ошибку вида "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...", но не "could not be resolved"

Comment: А, это похоже плагин pylance выводит. Выберите в левом нижнем углу vscode интерпретатор python, для которого установлен пакет xlrd. Если установлено несколько разных версий python, удалите "лишние", чтобы не путаться (это не обязательно, но если вы новичок, то проще работать с одним интерпретатором)

Comment: "Я вводил в терминале pip install xlrd , pip3 install xlrd , но это не помогло." - для полноты картины стоит указать в вопросе, что выводится при команде `pip install xlrd`

Comment: У меня вроде не установлен пакет xlrd . может быть поэтому ошибка?

Comment: Если не установлен, то нужно установить с помощью команды `pip install xlrd`. Если не устанавливается, то нужно указать текст, который выводит эта команда.

Comment: `Я вводил в терминале pip install xlrd , pip3 install xlrd , но это не помогло.` нужно убедиться что у вас питон, который глобально доступен в системе тот же, через который вы запускаете скрипт, т.к. может у вас используются виртуальные окружения env / venv

Comment: Да, желательно указать операционную систему (я исхожу из предположения, что у вас Windows, но я могу ошибаться).

Comment: Да у меня `Windows`, но как и где мне указать это?

Comment: "pip не распознано как имя командлета и прочее" - это вывод powershell, значит Windows, значит при установке Python нужно было указать, что нужно добавить его в переменные окружения (environment variables, PATH, или что-то в этом роде). Переустановите Python с включением этой галки, после этого pip должен стать доступен из командной строки. "Да у меня Windows, но как и где мне указать это?" - в вопросе или в комментарии - это нужно (было) для того, чтобы понять, как вам помочь.